# exponential distribution question (poisson process)

Tags: probability

> Particles are emitted from a radioactive material in a Poisson process
>   of rate $\lambda$ per unit time. What is the mean time between
>   emissions? If the last particle was emitted $L$ time units ago, what
>   is the distribution of the time till the next emission (starting now)?

The solution goes as follows. Let $X$ be the time between emissions. Then $X \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ hence $E(X) = 1/\lambda$.

Then we are looking for $P(X-L>x | X>L)$ for $x>0$. The author then and calculates that conditional probability.

What I don't understand is why we are calculating that.

My ideas: We know that $X>L$, so the remaining time for the next emission is $X-L$ but what I don't understand is why the author is looking for $" X-L>x"$. How does this give the desired distribution we're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(X-L>x | X>L)$ means the probability that the time to the next emission (i.e. the length of the time from the last emission to the next emission  minus the time already passed since the last emission given the time already passed) is greater than some specified $x$.

If this does not make the conditional distribution obvious (memorylessness is involved in this particular case) then you could then subtract this probability from $1$ to give the conditional cumulative distribution function and take the derivative with respect to $x$ of that to find the conditional density.  The conditional distribution should then be easy to spot.